# How to create in-app message thread using postgres

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, reactjs, sequelize.js

What is the best way to create a message model/controller that accounts for replies and creates a message thread?

This is what my message controller looks like so far

```

```
/**
 * messages controller
 */

var _ = require('lodash')

var models = require('../models');
var Message = models.Message;

// Expose the message controller.
module.exports = {

  // POST /api/message
  create: function(req, res) {
    var data = _.pick(req.body, 'user_id', 'from', 'to', 'subject', 'body');
    Message
      .build(data)
      .save()
      .complete(function (err, message) {
        if (!err && message) {
          res.json(message);
          res.status(200);
          return;
        }
        // res.json(err)
        res.json({
          error: 'Invalid.'
        })
        res.status(406);
      });
  },

  // GET /api/messages/:id
  get: function(req, res) {
    var id = req.params.id;
    Message
      .find({
        where: {
          id: id
        },
        // include: [models.Reply]
      }).then(function (message) {
        res.json(message);
      }).complete(function (err, message) {
        if (!err && message) {
          res.json(message);
          res.status(200);
          return;
        }
        // res.json(err)
        res.json({
          error: 'Invalid.'
        })
        res.status(406);
      });
  },

  reply: function(req, res) {
    var id = req.params.id;
    Message
      .find({
        where: {
          id: id
        }
      }).then(function(reply){

      })
  },

  destroy: function(req, res) {
  }

};
```

What would I put in the reply method?

This would be a corresponding json that it should be able to persist

```
{
    id: 1,
    name: "Inbox",
    emails: [
      {
        id: 1,
        from: "joe@tryolabs.com",
        to: "fernando@tryolabs.com",
        subject: "Meeting",
        body: "hi"
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        from: "newsbot@tryolabs.com",
        to: "fernando@tryolabs.com",
        subject: "News Digest",
        body: "<h1>Intro to React</h1> <img src='https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wiki/facebook/react/react-logo-1000-transparent.png' width=300/)>"
      }
    ]
  }
```